# Как запустить код?

Tags: qbasic, запуск

Дан листинг программы на Qbasic. Как его запустить?

```
OPEN "COM2:19200,N,8,1" FOR RANDOM AS #1 
Start: 
    CLS 
ST: LOCATE 1, 1 
    PRINT "1.  
Запрос
показаний
индикации
.                      " 
    PRINT "2.  
Опрос
показаний
индикации
.                       " 
    PRINT "3.  
Опрос
координаты
Х
.                              " 
    PRINT "4.  
Опрос
координаты
У
.                              " 
    PRINT "5.  
Выход
.                                           " 
    PRINT "----------------------------------------
-------------" 
    LOCATE 8, 1: INPUT "
Номер
команды
"; num 
    GOSUB CLSCR 
    SELECT CASE num 
      CASE 1 
        PRINT #1, "CP" 
        c$ = INPUT$(1, 1) 
        kk = ASC(c$) 
        LOCATE 9, 1 
        DO WHILE c$ <> CHR$(0) 
          IF kk = 13 THEN c$ = "                   
         " + c$ 
          PRINT c$; 
          c$ = INPUT$(1, 1) 
          kk = ASC(c$) 
        LOOP 
      CASE 2 
LOOP1:  PRINT #1, "CP"
        c$ = INPUT$(1, 1) 
        kk = ASC(c$)
LOCATE 9, 1 
        DO WHILE c$ <> CHR$(0) 
          IF kk = 13 THEN c$ = "                   
          " + c$ 
          PRINT c$; 
          c$ = INPUT$(1, 1) 
          kk = ASC(c$) 
        LOOP 
        GOSUB CLSCR2 
        IF INKEY$ = "" GOTO LOOP1 
        GOTO Start 
      CASE 3 
        GOSUB CLSCR2 
LOOP2:  PRINT #1, "CX" 
        c$ = INPUT$(1, 1) 
        kk = ASC(c$) 
        LOCATE 9, 1 
        PRINT "Xt="; 
        DO WHILE c$ <> CHR$(0) 
          IF kk = 13 THEN c$ = "                   
        " + c$ 
          PRINT c$; 
          c$ = INPUT$(1, 1) 
          kk = ASC(c$) 
        LOOP 
        PRINT " 
мм
.                                        "
        IF INKEY$ = "" GOTO LOOP2 
        GOTO Start 
      CASE 4 
        GOSUB CLSCR2 
LOOP3:  PRINT #1, "CY" 
        c$ = INPUT$(1, 1) 
        kk = ASC(c$) 
        LOCATE 9, 1 
        PRINT "Yt="; 
        DO WHILE c$ <> CHR$(0) 
          IF kk = 13 THEN c$ = "                   
        " + c$ 
          PRINT c$; 
          c$ = INPUT$(1, 1) 
          kk = ASC(c$) 
        LOOP 
        PRINT " 
мм
.                                       " 
        IF INKEY$ = "" GOTO LOOP3 
        GOTO Start 
      CASE 5 
        STOP 
  CASE ELSE 
    END SELECT 
    GOTO ST 
CLSCR: 
    LOCATE 8, 16: PRINT "                     " 
    FOR i = 9 TO 23 
      PRINT "                                      
             " 
    NEXT 
    LOCATE 9, 1 
    RETURN 
CLSCR2: 
    FOR i = 10 TO 11 
      PRINT "                                      
             " 
    NEXT
    RETURN
```

Comment: *не знаю как запустить* Находим и копируем к себе Qbasic, запускаем, загружаем и запускаем программу.

Comment: @Akina Не понимаю как мне в Qbasic'e это запустить. Он ругнулся на поддержку полного экрана, потом на расположение и вообще закрылся сам. Это QB.exe,
а BC.exe кучу всего просит, чего у меня просто нет

Comment: Ну вообще-то QB не любит новых ОС... запустите его в DOSBOX. Правда, насчёт прямого управления компортом я что-то сильно сомневаюсь.

Comment: @Akina И мне сам этот листинг нужно сохранить в расширении .bas, а затем ввести полный путь до него? Или ещё какие-нибудь особенности есть?

Comment: См. доку на DOSBOX. К формируемому сеансу подключается каталог аки диск - файл нужно положить туда. Расширение некритично, хотя BAS - желательно. Впрочем, текст программы можно будет скопипастить прямо в окно эдитора QB.

Comment: Как вариант попробуйте free basic, он по идее должен понимать код, написанный для QB.